# Custom View not rendered when defined in a loop inside onBindViewHolder

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created a custom view ButtonView and I want to show it dynamically in a GridLayout inside a RecyclerView. 
Inside onBindViewHolder of the RecyclerView Adapter, I fetch the gridLayout and put ButtonViews dynamically.

```
for(Appliance appliance : appliances){
            ButtonView appliance_button = new ButtonView(context, as);
            appliance_button.setCircleText(appliance.getApplianceName());
            gridLayout.addView(appliance_button);
        }
```

So if the Appliance list has 4 items I should get 4 ButtonViews rendered but I get only the first one rendered. Please help me to get all the 4 appliance rendered.

The code of the ButtonView is:

```
public class ButtonView extends View {

//circle and text colors
private int circleCol =android.R.color.holo_blue_light, labelCol = android.R.color.black;

private boolean isChecked, isAuto;
public boolean isChecked() {
    return isChecked;
}

public void setChecked(boolean isChecked) {
    this.isChecked = isChecked;
    if(isAuto){
        setAuto(false);
    }
    if(isChecked){
        setLabelCol(onColor);
    }else{
        setLabelCol(offColor);
    }
}

public boolean isAuto() {
    return isAuto;
}

public void setAuto(boolean isAuto) {
    this.isAuto = isAuto;
    if(isAuto){
        setOuterCirclePaint(autoColor);
    }else{
        setOuterCirclePaint(normalColor);
    }
}

private int offColor = android.R.color.darker_gray, onColor = android.R.color.black, autoColor = android.R.color.holo_green_light, normalColor = android.R.color.black;

private void setLabelCol(int labelCol) {
    this.labelCol = labelCol;
    invalidate();
}

public String getCircleText() {
    return circleText;
}

public void setCircleText(String circleText) {
    this.circleText = circleText;
    invalidate();
}


private void setOuterCirclePaint(int outerCirclePaint) {
    this.outerCirclePaint = outerCirclePaint;
    invalidate();
}

//label text
private String circleText = "Appliance";
//paint for drawing custom view
private Paint circlePaint;

private int outerCirclePaint;

public ButtonView(Context context)
{
    super(context);
    init(context);
}
public ButtonView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs);

    circlePaint = new Paint();
    //get the attributes specified in attrs.xml using the name we included
    TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
            R.styleable.ButtonView, 0, 0);

    try {
        //get the text and colors specified using the names in attrs.xml
        circleText = a.getString(R.styleable.ButtonView_circleLabel);
        circleCol = a.getInteger(R.styleable.ButtonView_circleColor, android.R.color.holo_blue_dark);//0 is default
        onColor = a.getInteger(R.styleable.ButtonView_onColor, android.R.color.white);
        offColor = a.getInteger(R.styleable.ButtonView_offColor, android.R.color.darker_gray);
        isAuto = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.ButtonView_isAuto, false);
        isChecked = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.ButtonView_isChecked, false);
        autoColor = a.getInteger(R.styleable.ButtonView_autoColor, android.R.color.holo_green_light);
        normalColor = a.getInteger(R.styleable.ButtonView_normalColor, android.R.color.black);


        if(isChecked){
            labelCol = onColor;
        }else{
            labelCol = offColor;
        }
        if(isAuto){
            outerCirclePaint = autoColor;
        }else{
            outerCirclePaint = normalColor;
        }


    } finally {
        a.recycle();
    }
}

private void init(Context context) {
    circlePaint = new Paint();
    //get the attributes specified in attrs.xml using the name we included
    TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.ButtonView);

    try {
        //get the text and colors specified using the names in attrs.xml
        circleText = a.getString(R.styleable.ButtonView_circleLabel);
        circleCol = a.getInteger(R.styleable.ButtonView_circleColor, android.R.color.holo_blue_dark);//0 is default
        onColor = a.getInteger(R.styleable.ButtonView_onColor, android.R.color.white);
        offColor = a.getInteger(R.styleable.ButtonView_offColor, android.R.color.darker_gray);
        isAuto = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.ButtonView_isAuto, false);
        isChecked = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.ButtonView_isChecked, false);
        autoColor = a.getInteger(R.styleable.ButtonView_autoColor, android.R.color.holo_green_light);
        normalColor = a.getInteger(R.styleable.ButtonView_normalColor, android.R.color.black);


        if(isChecked){
            labelCol = onColor;
        }else{
            labelCol = offColor;
        }
        if(isAuto){
            outerCirclePaint = autoColor;
        }else{
            outerCirclePaint = normalColor;
        }


    } finally {
        a.recycle();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    int viewWidthHalf = this.getMeasuredWidth()/10;
    int viewHeightHalf = this.getMeasuredHeight()/10;

    int radius = 0;
    if(viewWidthHalf>viewHeightHalf)
        radius=viewHeightHalf-10;
    else
        radius=viewWidthHalf-10;

    circlePaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
    circlePaint.setAntiAlias(true);

    //set the paint color using the circle color specified
    circlePaint.setColor(circleCol);

    canvas.drawCircle(viewWidthHalf, viewHeightHalf, radius, circlePaint);

    circlePaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
    circlePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    circlePaint.setStrokeWidth(10);

    //set the paint color using the circle color specified
    circlePaint.setColor(outerCirclePaint);
    canvas.drawCircle(viewWidthHalf, viewHeightHalf, radius, circlePaint);



    Typeface tf = Typeface.create(Typeface.SANS_SERIF, Typeface.NORMAL);
    circlePaint.setTypeface(tf);

    //set the text color using the color specified
    circlePaint.setColor(labelCol);


    //set text properties
    circlePaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
    circlePaint.setStrokeWidth(0);
    circlePaint.setTextSize(20);

    if(circleText.length() > 10){
        circleText = circleText.substring(0, 10);
        circleText = circleText + "..";
    }
    //draw the text using the string attribute and chosen properties
    canvas.drawText(circleText, viewWidthHalf, viewHeightHalf, circlePaint);
}
```

}

Comment: Are you sure addView is called four times?  did you use hierarchyviewer to see the view hierarchy?

Comment: Yes, i checked it using the breakpoint. I checked the number of children of the GridLyout as well, it was 4.

Comment: print count of appliances in log

Comment: what if you for testing replace ButtonView with ordinary Button/TextView/View ? Or replace GridLayout with LinearLayout

Comment: I replaced the ButtonView with Button, 4 Buttons are rendered.

Comment: Please provide your custom ButtonView code.

Comment: override `onMeasure` and give your ButtonView some size, now it seems that viewWidthHalf and viewHeightHalf are both 0

Comment: Thanks pskink, I added onMeasure and it showed the rendering. Earlier I was sending the layout_height and layout_width in the attribute set itself , so I thought I would not need anything else to set the height and the width. But I removed it and now I am putting it in onMeasure itself.